# Translate null data to zero

Tags: qgis

I have a raster with null data. I want to create a mask for where ever I have values in my raster. (not null cells)
When I use translate(convert format) in qgis (Raster-->conversion--> translate)to transfer the no data in the original file to 0, instead of changing nodata to 0, it is changing them to -999!

And when I use raster calculator and divide the raster by itself to create mask and then using translate to convert null data to 0,  the tool convert the null values to 3.4028234663852886e+38. How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Your input raster has both values pixels and pixel with null value?

Answer (score 1):

I am making an assumption that:

- Originally, NoData value of your raster layer was `-999`.
- On `Translate (convert format)` window, you chose `No Data` option and set it to `zero (0)`.

All `0` cells are now regarded as NoData cells in your new layer, while `-999` cells became visible.

Your second raster calculation involved division by zero (i.e. current NoData), then QGIS returned maximum value for float (3.4E+38).

Having said that, what you are trying to do is change -999 to 0. You can do it by Raster calculator, but if it fails, consider using SAGA `Reclassify values` tool in the Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

To create a raster layer with values wherever your input raster is not null, do the following in raster calculator:
*You can also convert format using this process if that is why you were using translate before*

```
(“RASTER_NAME” is not null ) = 1
```

[image: raster Calculator Mask not null]